# Mapping local volume and port binding for Postgres container in k8s/Skaffold

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, skaffold

I'm under the impression that the equivalent of the following command can't be put into a `Dockerfile` or `Dockerfile.dev`:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -v /home/app/database/db-files:/var/lib/postgresql/data sockpuppet/database
```

The `-p 5432:5432` I was using to bind to the local port so I could connect to Postgres with pgAdmin. This is not an absolute requirement, but a nice to have. **Perhaps there is a better way of doing this?**

The `-v /home/app/database/db-files:/var/lib/postgresql/data` so I can persist data on the local volume.

The problem is `EXPOSE` in a `Dockerfile`, as far as I know, just opens ports between containers. The problem with `VOLUME` in a `Dockerfile` is that it just refers to the image's file system.

The bigger issue I'm having a hard time understanding is the Skaffold `skaffold.yaml` refers to these `Dockerfile``Dockerfile.dev` when running the containers:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v1beta2
kind: Config
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: sockpuppet/client
      context: client
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      sync:
        '**/*.js': .
        '**/*.css': .
        '**/*.html': .
    - image: sockpuppet/server
      context: server
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      sync:
        '**/*.js': .
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - k8s/client-deployment.yaml
      - k8s/server-deployment.yaml
      - k8s/server-cluster-ip-service.yaml
      - k8s/client-cluster-ip-service.yaml
```

So how am I supposed to bind ports and map volumes if they can't be specified in `Dockerfile`? Do I just need to run `docker run -p 5432:5432 -v /home/app/database/db-files:/var/lib/postgresql/data ishraqiyun77/database` manually every time I want to start up the DB?

Repo I'm using as a reference if that is helpful: https://github.com/StephenGrider/DockerCasts/tree/master/complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `skaffold.yaml` is there to help with build and deployment of `k8s`.  If you want to do port-exposing and volume mapping, you should do that in the various `.yaml` files in the `manifests` section.  The `EXPOSE` keyword in your `Dockerfile`s simply tells the newly-created image which ports to allow for exposing and forwarding; it is only in your `k8s` containers that you actually do the mapping of ports and volumes to the host machine.

Disclosure: I am an [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://enterprisedb.com) employee